# How to disable window resize in windows universal app?

Tags: c#

When I create a new Windows Universal app and launch it I can resize borders of it.  How can I to disable this functionality?

In comparison to *WPF* you can set the `ResizeMode` property to `ResizeMode.NoResize`.  I tried to implemented this in my project, but it didn't work properly.

Comment: I really use google but found nothing.

Comment: Me too , i find nothing... really weird . Seems like a basic feature by the way